# Notation for localised ring in Hartshorne's "Algebraic Geometry"

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization

I am having trouble with the proposition in the picture below, particularly regarding the notation of the localised ring $A_f$. I really can not figure out what it could mean (with certainty), and would appreciate any help.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A_f$ denotes $A$ localised at the multiplicatively closed subset $\{f^n:n\geq0\}$, so elements are of the form $\frac{a}{f^m}$.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, as a tip for the future, Hartshorne (and a lot of other textbooks) have an "Index of Notation" at the back. If you're not sure what something means, that should give you a brief description and tell you the page where it was defined/first used.